# Heroku mongo_mapper MONGOHQ_URL unparseable by ruby uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, mongomapper

I have scoured the Internet without finding an adequate solution, so I'm here to ask the SO community for help.

I'm migrating a rails 2 app on Heroku Bamboo to Cedar. Concomitantly, I am moving to rails 3 and ruby 2.0.0 (though I get this error with ruby 1.9.3 as well).

It seems that MongoMapper has undergone a bit a change from 0.8.6, to the point where I can't use our old initializer anymore. I'm attempting to use the latest 0.13.1 version of mongo_mapper.

According to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq, I just need to set `config/mongo.yml` to:

```
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

and I'm all set (I also commented out the old initializer code). However, it fails with the following connection error:

> Feb 05 11:18:28 my-app-name app/web.1:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme mongodb does not accept registry part: heroku:2QMdYzo6z5nmJJsmWAWKd_205umc05tBuP2ZodGaNDZ7N5rE4ns09jhsfFBjmkQ2ls_rfTiVC0lD24Y2byDXbg@candidate.21.mongolayer.com:10499,candidate.4.mongolayer.com:10625 (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)

An invalid URI is understandable, but that's what being fed to me by Heroku. What do I am missing in order to for the uri parser to accept it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the presence of that comma (,) in the uri. When I removed the second host and the comma, it behaved correctly :-)

Specifically, I created a Heroku ENV variable called `MONGOHQ_URL2` without the second host name, then updated my `config/mongo.yml` to use that one instead.

Comment: The question remains, how can you specify a second host? If mongomapper will only take one host, then we lose the reliability that is supposed to come from having a mongo cluster.